# How do I set the Id of a specific element in a class?

Tags: javascript, class, dynamic, getelementbyid

I have dynamically loaded content and I need to set the id of a specific element.  How do I do this?

Comment: Sounds like it should have had an ID in the first place. Otherwise, how do you intend to identify it?

Comment: i have access to the content I just need to know how to give it an id

Comment: @Davis: Give _what_ an ID? How do you choose what ID goes on which element?

Answer (score 0):

Customize your dynamic rendering to have id attribute. If you don't have control over it, try accessing the DOM objects using some other ways like 'name','class','custom attribute'.

If you can not distinguish between your objects, then probably you are doing it wrong.

btw, if you want to do it desperately, you can do like below using jquery.

```
$(".myclass").attr('id','myID');
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your question, you can assign an id with the following example:

```
// find the first span on the page and assign it an ID
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
if(spans.length > 0) {
  spans[0].id = 'your-id';
}
```

Most likey your business logic is more complicated then this. You'll need to traverse the dom using getElementsByTagName, etc to reach the desired node, then assign the id.

A quicker option would be to use a library such as jquery that allows you to quickly query nodes within the dom, and apply attributes:

```
$('your>business.logic').attr('id', 'your-id');
```